# Ajustar alto de div automáticamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo una consulta
Tengo en un div contenedor que adentro tiene dos divs, uno arriba y uno abajo, el de arriba va a variar el contenido y el alto y el de abajo quiero que ocupe todo el espacio restante, ¿es esto posible?

Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.formulario {
  background: green;
}

.title {
  background: #FF8C8E;
  height: 30px;
}

.results {
  background: #D699FF;
  height: calc( 100% - 235px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="formulario" class="formulario">
    Prueba:<br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="title" class="title"></div>
  <div id="results" class="results">
    hola
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: que has intentado?

Comment: @element Edité la pregunta con lo que he intentado, no me funciona con el calc() del div de abajo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no necesitas compatibilidad "cross-browser" (por IE9 y anteriores) puedes utilizar `flexbox` de la siguiente forma:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.formulario {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.results {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

[Más info sobre flexbox (inglés)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Una muestra aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-iwiqem?file=style.css)

Comment: Muchas gracias! No busco compatibilidad con navegadores más antiguos y el código que me pasaste me solucionó el problema :)

Answer (score 0):

Parafrasearé la instrucción, le estás diciendo al `div#results` tu altura será del 100% ( Lo tomará del padre, es decir de `div.container` ) pero el `div.container` tiene una altura del 100%, y es aquí el problema, por que no sabe la altura respecto a quien. El `div.container` así como lo pones está embebido en `html > body` pero estas etiquetas no les has dicho cuanto miden entonces hay que agregarlo

```
body, html{ height: 100%; }
```

Al último `html` tomará la altura del `window` y ya no hay más arriba, entonces ya tenemos lo que estás buscando.
También quité el `calc()` de `div.results`

Espero te sirva

```css
body, html{ height: 100%; } 
.container {
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.formulario {
  background: green;
}

.title {
  background: #FF8C8E;
  height: 30px;
}

.results {
  background: #D699FF;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="formulario" class="formulario">
    Prueba:<br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br> Prueba:
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="title" class="title"></div>
  <div id="results" class="results">
    hola
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He intentado con el código que me diste, pero resulta que el div no se ajusta al alto de la pantalla si no que lo sobrepasa y hay que hacer scroll

Comment: Utiliza 100vh, que hará que tu documento tenga un alto igual al alto de tu ventana.